# Pattern-match (destructure) in equality proof

Tags: idris

```
data T = A String | B String

p : ((A s) = (A s')) -> (s = s')
```

If I have `(A s) = (A s')`, how do I obtain `s = s'`?

P.S. I'm new to Idris. Feel free to edit my question for code style or to add pertinent keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern match on `Refl`:

```
data T = A String | B String

p : ((A s) = (A s')) -> (s = s')
p Refl = Refl
```